# What is the instruction that gives branchless FP min and max on x86?

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, floating-point, x86

To quote (thanks to the author for developing and sharing the algorithm!):

https://tavianator.com/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections/

> Since modern floating-point instruction sets can compute min and max without branches

Corresponding code by the author is just

```
dmnsn_min(double a, double b)
{
  return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

I'm familiar with e.g. `_mm_max_ps`, but that's a vector instruction. The code above obviously is meant to be used in a scalar form.

Question:

- What is the scalar branchless minmax instruction on x86? Is it a sequence of instructions?
- Is it safe to assume it's going to be applied, or how do I call it?
- Does it make sense to bother about branchless-ness of min/max? From what I understand, for a raytracer and / or other viz software, given a ray - box intersection routine, there is no reliable pattern for the branch predictor to pick up, hence it does make sense to eliminate the branch. Am I right about this?
- Most importantly, the algorithm discussed is built around comparing against (+/-) INFINITY. Is this reliable w.r.t the (unknown) instruction we're discussing and the floating-point standard?

Just in case: I'm familiar with [Use of min and max functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632145/use-of-min-and-max-functions-in-c), believe it's related but not quite my question.

Comment: `_mm_max_ps` has the scalar equivalent `_mm_max_ss`

Comment: True, but isn't that a function that requires the compiler to perform auto-vectorization or hand-vectorization by the user?

Comment: Well, it's to show the instruction exists. The compiler can just use it whenever it needs it.

Comment: @iksemyonov See this worked example of scalar usage at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/UEJuIV)

Comment: For FPU, see `fcomi` and `fcmov`

Comment: @njuffa: or more simply: `float maxfloat(float a, float b) { return (a>b) ? a : b; }` compiles to `maxss   xmm0, xmm1` / `ret`, which demonstrates that compilers know how to use these instructions on their own.  But be careful to write in a way that is compatible with the NaN-handling behaviour of MAXPS/MINPS.  Interestingly, gcc before 7.0 treats `_mm_min_ps` as commutative, even though MINPS has asymmetric NaN-handling behaviour.  This is probably a bug, since clang and ICC both care about arg order (without -ffast-math).  See [this example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/XKLwHn).

Comment: @PeterCordes nice to see you here! Looking forward to reading your answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am aware of that, but was addressing the question "isn't that a function that requires the compiler to perform auto-vectorization or hand-vectorization". As far as I know, the machine instructions `MIN{P|S}S`, `MAX{P|S}S` are not fully compliant with IEEE-754 (2008), otherwise the standard math functions `fmin()`, `fmax()` could be mapped to them, which would be the cleanest C solution.

Comment: @njuffa: Well, they don't implement the IEEE `fmin`/`fmax` functions, but MINPS does exactly implement `(a<b) ? a : b` according to IEEE rules.  If that works for your use-case, then use it.  That's basically a TL:DR summary of my answer; I didn't see the OP asking for `fmin` semantics.  Your example of scalar intrinsics is useful, but note that gcc compiles your function to total crap, because it doesn't optimize away the `_mm_set_ss()` (see [my open question on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318496/how-to-merge-a-scalar-into-a-vector-without-the-compiler-wasting-an-instruction))

Comment: @PeterCordes   Since OP did not ask for `fmin()`, `fmax()` behavior, I didn't suggest it to them, although personally, that would be my preference (it is the most straightforward C code, and I am used to work on platforms where that maps straight to a machine instruction; was taken aback to find out that's still not true for x86). I also have no nits to pick with your answer, so I think we are in "violent agreement" :-)

Comment: @njuffa yeah why do mention those `fm{in|ax}` functions, I kept them in mind, having read the question I linked to, do they handle infinity correctly?

Comment: @PeterCordes I use icpc for release :p g++ for development because it's faster and produces readable errors where icpc makes Rosetta stone texts.

Comment: @iksemyonov I use the Intel compiler on Windows with `mathimf.h`, and with `/fp:strict` (equivalent on Linux: `-fp-model strict`), the behavior of `fmin()`, `fmax()` and their single-precision equivalents appears fully compliant with IEEE-754 (2008), including the handling of all special values. These are *not* single-instruction implementations, though.

Comment: @njuffa: Just updated my answer to point out that MINPS's behaviour is actually *useful* for SIMD conditionals.  This might be why Intel implemented it this way, many years before SSE4.1 BLENDVPS existed, instead of implementing the IEEE fmin/fmax functions.  (Or maybe they decided / found that more code used `std::min` instead of `fmin`).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Warning: Beware of compilers treating `_mm_min_ps` / `_mm_max_ps` (and _pd) intrinsics as commutative even in strict FP (not fast-math) mode; even though the asm instruction isn't.  GCC specifically seems to have this bug: [PR72867](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=72867) which was fixed in GCC7 but may be back or never fixed for `_mm_min_ss` etc. scalar intrinsics ([_mm_max_ss has different behavior between clang and gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553905/mm-max-ss-has-different-behavior-between-clang-and-gcc), GCC bugzilla [PR99497](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99497)).

GCC knows how the asm instructions themselves work, and doesn't have this problem when using them to implement strict FP semantics in plain scalar code, only with the C/C++ intrinsics.

Unfortunately there isn't a single instruction that implements `fmin(a,b)` (with guaranteed NaN propagation), so you have to choose between easy detection of problems vs. higher performance.

---

**Most vector FP instructions have scalar equivalents**.  [MINSS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MINSS.html) / MAXSS / MINSD / MAXSD are what you want.  They handle +/-Infinity the way you'd expect.

**`MINSS a,b` *exactly* implements `(a<b) ? a : b` according to IEEE rules**, with everything that implies about signed-zero, NaN, and Infinities.  (i.e. it keeps the source operand, `b`, on unordered.)  This means C++ compilers can use them for `std::min(b,a)` and `std::max(b,a)`, because those functions are based on the same expression.  **Note the `b,a` operand order for the `std::` functions**, opposite Intel-syntax for x86 asm, but matching AT&T syntax.

`MAXSS a,b` *exactly* implements `(b<a) ? a : b`, again keeping the source operand (`b`) on unordered.  Like `std::max(b,a)`.

Looping over an array with `x = std::min(arr[i], x);` (i.e. `minss` or `maxss xmm0, [rsi]`) will take a NaN from memory if one is present, and then take whatever non-NaN element is next because that compare will be unordered.  So you'll get the min or max of the elements following the last NaN.  You normally don't want this, so it's only good for arrays that don't contain NaN.  But it means you can start with `float v = NAN;` outside a loop, instead of the first element or FLT_MAX or +Infinity, and might simplify handling possibly-empty lists.  It's also convenient in asm, allowing init with `pcmpeqd xmm0,xmm0` to generate an all-ones bit-pattern (a negative QNAN), but unfortunately GCC's NAN uses a different bit-pattern.

Demo/proof [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:9,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:9,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:9,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:21),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0A//+opposite+compare+order+to+std::min,+at+least+to+libstdc%2B%2B!%27s+implementation.%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0AT+mymin(T+a,+T+b)%7B+++++++//+asm:+minss+a,+b%0A++++return+a%3Cb+%3F+a+:+b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+overall+min+and+max+before+the+NAN%0Afloat+arr%5B%5D+%3D+%7B4.0,+0.1,+NAN,+1.5,+0.5,+2.0%7D%3B%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++float+v+%3D+arr%5B0%5D%3B%0A++++//v+%3D+NAN%3B%0A++++for+(float+f+:+arr)+%7B%0A++++//for+(int+i+%3D+0+%3B+i%3Csizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr%5B0%5D)+%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B+float+f+%3D+arr%5Bi%5D%3B+++++//+C+version%0A++++++++//v+%3D+mymin(v,+f)%3B++++++++//+asm:+minss+xmm0,+%5Bmem%5D%0A++++++++//v+%3D+std::min(v,+f)%3B+++++++//+asm:+minss+f,+v++with+a+separate+load%0A++++++++v+%3D+std::min(f,+v)%3B+++++++//+asm:+minss+v,+%5Bmem%5D%0A%0A++++++++//v+%3D+std::max(v,+f)%3B+++++++//+asm:+separate+load,+maxss+f,+v%0A++++++++//v+%3D+std::max(f,+v)%3B+++++++//+asm:+maxss+v,+mem%0A++++%7D%0A++++printf(%22%25f%5Cn%22,+v)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O1%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:66.59939455095862,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:33.40060544904138,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), including showing that `v = std::min(v, arr[i]);` (or max) **ignores NaNs in the array**, at the cost of having to load into a register and then minss into that register.

(Note that min of an array should use vectors, not scalar; preferably with multiple accumulators to hide FP latency.  At the end, reduce to one vector then do [horizontal min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction/35270026#35270026) of it, just like summing an array or doing a dot product.)

---

**Don't try to use `_mm_min_ss` on scalar floats; the intrinsic is only available with `__m128` operands**, and [Intel's intrinsics don't provide any way to get a scalar float into the low element of a `__m128` without zeroing the high elements or somehow doing extra work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318496/how-to-merge-a-scalar-into-a-vector-without-the-compiler-wasting-an-instruction)  Most compilers will actually emit the useless instructions to do that even if the final result doesn't depend on anything in the upper elements. (Clang can often avoid it, though, applying the as-if rule to the contents of dead vector elements.)  There's nothing like `__m256 _mm256_castps128_ps256 (__m128 a)` to just cast a float to a `__m128` with garbage in the upper elements.  I consider this a design flaw. :/

**But fortunately you don't need to do this manually, compilers know how to use SSE/SSE2 min/max for you.**  Just write your C such that they can.  The function in your question is ideal: as shown below (Godbolt link):

```
// can and does inline to a single MINSD instruction, and can auto-vectorize easily
static inline double
dmnsn_min(double a, double b) {
  return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

---

**Note their asymmetric behaviour with NaN**: if the operands are unordered, dest=src (i.e. it takes the second operand if either operand is NaN).  This can be useful for SIMD conditional updates, see below.

(`a` and `b` are unordered if either of them is NaN.  That means `a<b`, `a==b`, and `a>b` are all false. See [Bruce Dawson's series of articles on floating point for lots of FP gotchas](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).)

The corresponding `_mm_min_ss` / `_mm_min_ps` intrinsics may or may not have this behaviour, depending on the compiler.

**I think the intrinsics are supposed to have the same operand-order semantics as the asm instructions, but gcc has treated the operands to `_mm_min_ps` as commutative even without `-ffast-math` for a long time, gcc4.4 or maybe earlier.  GCC 7 finally changed it to match ICC and clang.**

Intel's online intrinsics finder doesn't document that behaviour for the function, but it's maybe not supposed to be exhaustive.  The asm insn ref manual doesn't say the intrinsic *doesn't* have that property; it just lists `_mm_min_ss` as the intrinsic for MINSS.

When I googled on `"_mm_min_ps" NaN`, I found [this real code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/master/lib/Runtime/Language/SimdFloat32x4OperationX86X64.cpp#L230) and some other discussion of using the intrinsic to handle NaNs, so clearly many people expect the intrinsic to behave like the asm instruction.  (This came up for some code I was writing yesterday, and I was already thinking of writing this up as a self-answered Q&A.)

Given the existence of this longstanding gcc bug, portable code that wants to take advantage of MINPS's NaN handling needs to take precautions.  The standard gcc version on many existing Linux distros will mis-compile your code if it depends on the order of operands to `_mm_min_ps`.  So you probably need an `#ifdef` to detect actual gcc (not clang etc), and an alternative.  Or just do it differently in the first place :/  Perhaps with a `_mm_cmplt_ps` and boolean AND/ANDNOT/OR.

Enabling `-ffast-math` also makes `_mm_min_ps` commutative on all compilers.

---

**As usual, compilers know how to use the instruction set to implement C semantics correctly**.  MINSS and MAXSS are [faster than anything you could do with a branch anyway](http://agner.org/optimize/), so just write code that can compile to one of those.

The commutative-`_mm_min_ps` issue applies to *only* the intrinsic: gcc knows exactly how MINSS/MINPS work, and uses them to correctly implement strict FP semantics (when you don't use -ffast-math).

You don't usually need to do anything special to get decent scalar code out of a compiler.  But if you *are* going to spend time caring about what instructions the compiler uses, you should probably start by manually vectorizing your code if the compiler isn't doing that.

(There may be rare cases where a branch is best, if the condition almost always goes one way and latency is more important than throughput.  MINPS latency is ~3 cycles, but a perfectly predicted branch adds 0 cycles to the dependency chain of the critical path.)

---

**In C++, use `std::min` and `std::max`**, which are defined in terms of `>` or `<`, and don't have the same requirements on NaN behaviour that `fmin` and `fmax` do.  **Avoid [`fmin` and `fmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmin) for performance unless you need their NaN behaviour.**

In C, I think just write your own `min` and `max` functions (or macros if you do it safely).

---

[C & asm on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1vofdj)

```
float minfloat(float a, float b) {
  return (a<b) ? a : b;
}
# any decent compiler (gcc, clang, icc), without any -ffast-math or anything:
    minss   xmm0, xmm1
    ret

// C++
float minfloat_std(float a, float b) { return std::min(a,b); }
  # This implementation of std::min uses (b<a) : b : a;
  # So it can produce the result only in the register that b was in
  # This isn't worse (when inlined), just opposite
    minss   xmm1, xmm0
    movaps  xmm0, xmm1
    ret


float minfloat_fmin(float a, float b) { return fminf(a, b); }

# clang inlines fmin; other compilers just tailcall it.
minfloat_fmin(float, float):
    movaps  xmm2, xmm0
    cmpunordss      xmm2, xmm2
    movaps  xmm3, xmm2
    andps   xmm3, xmm1
    minss   xmm1, xmm0
    andnps  xmm2, xmm1
    orps    xmm2, xmm3
    movaps  xmm0, xmm2
    ret
   # Obviously you don't want this if you don't need it.
```

---

If you want to use `_mm_min_ss` / `_mm_min_ps` yourself, write code that lets the compiler make good asm even without -ffast-math.

If you don't expect NaNs, or want to handle them specially, write stuff like

```
lowest = _mm_min_ps(lowest, some_loop_variable);
```

so the register holding `lowest` can be updated in-place (even without AVX).

---

### Taking advantage of MINPS's NaN behaviour:

Say your scalar code is something like

```
if(some condition)
    lowest = min(lowest, x);
```

Assume the condition can be vectorized with CMPPS, so you have a vector of elements with the bits all set or all clear.  (Or maybe you can get away with ANDPS/ORPS/XORPS on floats directly, if you just care about their sign and don't care about negative zero.  This creates a truth value in the sign bit, with garbage elsewhere.  BLENDVPS looks at only the sign bit, so this can be super useful.  Or you can broadcast the sign bit with `PSRAD xmm, 31`.)

The straight-forward way to implement this would be to blend `x` with `+Inf` based on the condition mask.  Or do `newval = min(lowest, x);` and blend newval into `lowest`.  (either BLENDVPS or AND/ANDNOT/OR).

But the trick is that **all-one-bits is a NaN, and a bitwise OR will propagate it**.  So:

```
__m128 inverse_condition = _mm_cmplt_ps(foo, bar);
__m128 x = whatever;


x = _mm_or_ps(x, condition);   // turn elements into NaN where the mask is all-ones
lowest = _mm_min_ps(x, lowest);  // NaN elements in x mean no change in lowest
//  REQUIRES NON-COMMUTATIVE _mm_min_ps: no -ffast-math
//  AND DOESN'T WORK AT ALL WITH MOST GCC VERSIONS.
```

So with only SSE2, and we've done a conditional MINPS in two extra instructions (ORPS and MOVAPS, unless loop unrolling allows the MOVAPS to disappear).

The alternative without SSE4.1 BLENDVPS is ANDPS/ANDNPS/ORPS to blend, plus an extra MOVAPS.  ORPS is more efficient than BLENDVPS anyway (it's 2 uops on most CPUs).

Comment: Speechless, and appreciated! Would give a bounty, not +10 if could. Will read once I finish some code making use of this raybox routine. Yeah, the low float thing bugs me too, sadly I don't know AVX yet, will get into it soon though.

Comment: @iksemyonov: you could click the "accept" check-box under the up/down vote arrows to give me another +15, and tell future readers that this answered your question :)

Comment: Suuure, it's just a habit to let the question hang for a while. After your answer it probably makes little sense to let it hang though. I'm responsible with accepting answers, no worries :)

Comment: @iksemyonov: Ok.  I think that usually if there's something the accepted answer missed, people will still write their own answer, or leave a comment.  But sure, it makes sense to wait until you've had a chance to try some of what I said in your own code and make sure it actually works :)

Comment: Right, I forgot the main reason for not-accepting: the fear of people passing by an accepted-answer question. Think I read that somewhere once and it stuck.

Comment: @iksemyonov: that's true, some people might not even look at a question if they see the OP doesn't need any more help.  OTOH, some people might be interested to see what the accepted answer looked like, now that there is one.  I'm not sure which would be best in terms of getting the most viewers for this answer I spent time writing :P

Comment: You did not say anything about signed zero. `fmin` and `fmax` also handle signed zero (though they don't have to) whereas `std::min` and std::max` to not http://stackoverflow.com/a/30915238/2542702. `fmin` and `fmax`.

Comment: I also am not sure it's good advice to avoid functions which handle NAN and zero. The point is that these happen when you don't expect it and so you think you don't need NAN and then you go chasing a bug because you did not handle NAN.

Comment: @Zboson: I forgot that [this was only a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196817/what-is-the-instruction-that-gives-branchless-fp-min-and-max-on-x86/40199125?noredirect=1#comment67665035_40196817).  Included it in the answer.

Comment: @Zboson: std::min and std::max handle NaN, they just handle it differently from fmin.  Although it's not hard to argue that the way they handle it is non-useful.

Comment: I mean `std::min` and `std::max` are not associative with respect to NAN and signed zero which can lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: I can't find the quote now but I read something by Kahan that these special numbers are not to be though of as rare exceptions but rather as protective measure or something like that.

Comment: I guess my main point is that many people think they don't need NAN when in fact they probably do. But that's really a gut feeling so I can't really debate it further.

Comment: @Zboson: yeah, I know what you mean.  NaNs are so good because they poison everything downstream, so you get NaNs in your result to tell you there's a problem.  Anything that defeats measure is a disadvantage.

Comment: @Zboson: but in many cases, you only encounter NaN while testing/developing some game code, or something.  Once you have it debugged, it never produces NaN.  There are cases when it's reasonably safe to use faster but worse NaN handling once you think your code works.  But other cases where it's not.

Comment: I meant commutative not associative.

Comment: The link 7 seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Cordes's answer is great, I just figured I'd jump in with some shorter point-by-point answers:

> - What is the scalar branchless minmax instruction on x86? Is it a sequence of instructions?

I was referring to `minss`/`minsd`.  And even other architectures without such instructions should be able to do this branchlessly with conditional moves.

> - Is it safe to assume it's going to be applied, or how do I call it?

`gcc` and `clang` will both optimize `(a < b) ? a : b` to `minss`/`minsd`, so I don't bother using intrinsics.  Can't speak to other compilers though.

> - Does it make sense to bother about branchless-ness of min/max? From what I understand, for a raytracer and / or other viz software, given a ray - box intersection routine, there is no reliable pattern for the branch predictor to pick up, hence it does make sense to eliminate the branch. Am I right about this?

The individual `a < b` tests are pretty much completely unpredictable, so it is very important to avoid branching for those.  Tests like `if (ray.dir.x != 0.0)` are very predictable, so avoiding those branches is less important, but it does shrink the code size and make it easier to vectorize.  The most important part is probably removing the divisions though.

> - Most importantly, the algorithm discussed is built around comparing against (+/-) INFINITY. Is this reliable w.r.t the (unknown) instruction we're discussing and the floating-point standard?

Yes, `minss`/`minsd` behave exactly like `(a < b) ? a : b`, including their treatment of infinities and NaNs.

Also, I wrote a [followup post](https://tavianator.com/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections-part-2-nans/) to the one you referenced that talks about NaNs and min/max in more detail.