# Why doesn't the C++ standard library include a non-const version of std::min, std::max?

Tags: c++

I vaguely remember I saw somewhere a discussion on this but I cannot find it now; "non-const min max c++" and similar variants give no relevant results.

Why doesn't the C++ standard library include the following non-const overload of `std::min` (and similarly for `std:max`)?

```
template <typename T>
T& min(T& a, T& b);
```

It could be useful sometimes, e.g. if I want to increase the lower number:

```
std::min(x, y) += 1;
```

Are there any problems this overload would cause?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/tnx2SaxEpYE

Comment: If they both have the *same value*, which one gets updated?

Comment: The first one, as per the standard behaviour of std::min, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min. “Returns: The smaller of a and b. If the values are equivalent, returns a.”

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was proposed by Howard E. Hinnant in [N2199: "Improved min/max"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2199.html), which according to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/tnx2SaxEpYE) was rejected.

In the same discussion Howard mentions these as the reasons for the rejection:

> The implementation was considered too complicated at the time.  Though
>   I haven’t tried, it could almost surely be done much more simply in
>   today’s language/library.  At the very least what is called “promote”
>   in the implementation is today called “std::common_type”.
>
> Part of the complication is that I attempted to solve several problems
>   at the same time:
>
> 1. Being able to assign into the result of min (but only when safe to do so).
> 2. Eliminate dangling reference dangers at compile-time.
> 3. Support heterogeneous integral comparisons, weeding out dangerous combinations at compile-time.
> 4. Support move-only types.

As T.C. mentions in the same discussion, a proposal would also need to not break code such as:

```
int i = 1; std::min(i, 0);
```

---

If you're interested in solving the problems mentioned in the discussion and writing a proposal + example implementation, then this could eventually make it into the Standard.

Comment: It's simple, call it `minref`, not overloaded `min`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: that name seems to imply that `min` doesn't return a reference.

Comment: then call it `minnonconstref` :P

Comment: Was there any discussion as to why this wasn't shipped in the first version of min/max? Simple oversight?

Comment: @Borgleader: I probably wasn't even born yet when that happened. I would assume no one proposed it in the first place...?

Comment: I can't remember if I read it of have seen it in a video but Alexander Stepanov says that min and/or max is implemented wrongly (it was very subtle mathematically) returning the wrong value when equal. Wouldn't that be an issue ?

Comment: @engf-010 - That's [*an* issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834117/why-use-b-a-a-b-instead-of-a-b-b-a-to-implement-max-template), but not the issue here.