# Why doesn't a const reference extend the life of a temporary object passed via a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, temporary-objects

In the following simple example, why can't `ref2` be bound to the result of `min(x,y+1)`?

```
#include <cstdio>
template< typename T > const T& min(const T& a, const T& b){ return a < b ? a : b ; }

int main(){
      int x = 10, y = 2;
      const int& ref = min(x,y); //OK
      const int& ref2 = min(x,y+1); //NOT OK, WHY?
      return ref2; // Compiles to return 0
}
```

[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/FZ1pX3) - produces:

```
main:
  xor eax, eax
  ret
```

**EDIT:**
  Below example better described a situation, I think.

```
#include <stdio.h>


template< typename T >
constexpr T const& min( T const& a, T const& b ) { return a < b ? a : b ; }



constexpr int x = 10;
constexpr int y = 2;

constexpr int const& ref = min(x,y);  // OK

constexpr int const& ref2 = min(x,y+1); // Compiler Error

int main()
{
      return 0;
}
```

[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Egj0Q6) produces:

```
<source>:14:38: error: '<anonymous>' is not a constant expression

 constexpr int const& ref2 = min(x,y+1);

                                      ^

Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: This program produces no output and exits with code 0. With `-O3` optimization flag all the statements inside of main are discarded.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: This is actually a very interesting question. I'll tag language lawyer and hope one of the chiefs picks this one up. I've neither the time nor the expertise. It's all to do with the fact that lifetime extension is not transitive, and where the original objects are located. Go on @StoryTeller.

Comment: By the way, prefer `return b < a ? b : a;` for the implementation.

Comment: @Bathsheba Could you quickly explain why `b < a ? b : a` that advantageous?

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of knowledge on C++, but this situation only makes sense isn't? The function returns a temporary object that does not live anywhere else. How can a reference refer to something that is not alive anymore?

Comment: @Michiel The thing is, if the binding was direct (e.g. if `min` was returning by value), `ref2` would extend the lifetime of the bound temporary to that of itself. Hence the question, I guess.

Comment: @lubgr: It's all about the convention of returning a particular parameter in the event of a tie or NaN: e.g. floating point signed zero.

Comment: @lubgr: Related: [Why use “b < a ? a : b” instead of “a < b ? b : a” to implement max template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834117/why-use-b-a-a-b-instead-of-a-b-b-a-to-implement-max-template)

Comment: @VTT; I'm confused. The program *does* produce output — the value "ref2" which is nominally min(10,3). I think I see the problem though. Because these are references, "y+1" resulted in a temporary variable to hold the value, the reference to that was passed to min(), which returned the temporary value, which then fell out of scope, leaving ref2 reference an invalid location. Do I have all that right?

Comment: @EdwardFalk The question has been edited since then. First variant did non use `ref2` and `NOT OK` part was actually completely OK (except that it did not bind to temporary, which was completely irrelevant).

Comment: There have been proposals (rejected?) to introduce a marker explicitly saying that a function may return a reference to a specific argument, and that any place where lifetime extension could have happened for a return value, it should instead happen for the argument. In this case, if `min` was marked on both arguments, it means that `const auto&z=min(x+1,y+1)` would extend the lifetime of both `x+1` and `y+1`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's by design. In a nutshell, only the *named* reference to which the temporary is bound *directly* will extend its lifetime.

> **[class.temporary]**
>
> 5 There are three contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a
>   different point than the end of the full-expression. [...]
>
> 6 The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.
>   The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is
>   the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call persists until the completion of the full-expression containing
>     the call.
> - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement is not extended; the temporary is destroyed
>     at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.
> - [...]

You didn't bind directly to `ref2`, and you even pass it via a return statement. The standard explicitly says it won't extend the lifetime. In part to make certain optimizations possible. But ultimately, because keeping track of which temporary should be extended when a reference is passed in and out of functions is intractable in general.

Since compilers may optimize aggressively on the assumption that your program exhibits no undefined behavior, you see a possible manifestation of that. Accessing a value outside its lifetime is undefined, this is what `return ref2;` *does*, and since the behavior is undefined, simply returning zero is a valid behavior to exhibit. No contract is broken by the compiler.

Comment: Thx a lot. I wrongly thought that,  `y+1`  temporary object bind to `b`  and it's live extends via return function. .

Answer (score 19):

This is intentional. A reference can only extend the lifetime of a temporary when it is bound to that temporary *directly*. In your code, you are binding `ref2` to the result of `min`, which is a reference. It doesn't matter that that reference references a temporary. Only `b` extends the lifetime of the temporary; it doesn't matter that `ref2` also refers to that same temporary.

Another way to look at it: You can't optionally have lifetime extension. It's a static property. If `ref2` would do the Correct Thing<sup>tm</sup>, then depending on the runtime values of `x` and `y+1` the lifetime is extended or not. Not something the compiler is able to do.

Answer (score 10):

I will answer the question first, and then provide some context for the answer. [The current working draft contains the following wording:](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6)

> The temporary object to which the reference is bound or the temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference if the glvalue to which the reference is bound was obtained through one of the following:
>
> - a temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]),
> - `(` *expression* `)`, where expression is one of these expressions,
> - subscripting ([expr.sub]) of an array operand, where that operand is one of these expressions,
> - a class member access ([expr.ref]) using the `.` operator where the left operand is one of these expressions and the right operand designates a non-static data member of non-reference type,
> - a pointer-to-member operation ([expr.mptr.oper]) using the `.*` operator where the left operand is one of these expressions and the right operand is a pointer to data member of non-reference type,
> - a `const_­cast` ([expr.const.cast]), `static_­cast` ([expr.static.cast]), `dynamic_­cast` ([expr.dynamic.cast]), or `reinterpret_­cast` ([expr.reinterpret.cast])
>     converting, without a user-defined conversion, a glvalue operand that is one of these expressions to a glvalue that refers to the object designated by the operand, or to its complete object or a subobject thereof,
> - a conditional expression ([expr.cond]) that is a glvalue where the second or third operand is one of these expressions, or
> - a comma expression ([expr.comma]) that is a glvalue where the right operand is one of these expressions.

According to this, when a reference is bound to a glvalue returned from a function call, lifetime extension does not occur, because the glvalue was obtained from the function call, which is not one of the permitted expressions for lifetime extension.

The lifetime of the `y+1` temporary is extended once when bound to the reference parameter `b`. Here, the prvalue `y+1` is materialized to yield an xvalue, and the reference is bound to the result of the temporary materialization conversion; lifetime extension thus occurs. When the `min` function returns, however, `ref2` is bound to the result of the call, and lifetime extension does not occur here. Therefore, the `y+1` temporary is destroyed at the end of the definition of `ref2`, and `ref2` becomes a dangling reference.

---

There has historically been some confusion on this topic. It is well-known that the OP's code and similar code result in a dangling reference, but the standard text, even as of C++17, did not provide an unambiguous explanation as to why.

It is often claimed that lifetime extension only applies when the reference binds "directly" to the temporary, but the standard has never said anything to that effect. Indeed, the standard defines what it means for a reference to "bind directly", and that definition (*e.g.*, `const std::string& s = "foo";` is an indirect reference binding) is clearly not relevant here.

Rakete1111 has said in a comment elsewhere on SO that lifetime extension only applies when the reference binds to a prvalue (rather than some glvalue that was obtained through a previous reference binding to that temporary object); they appear to be saying something similar here by "bound ... directly". However, there is no textual support for this theory. Indeed, code like the following has sometimes been considered to trigger lifetime extension:

```
struct S { int x; };
const int& r = S{42}.x;
```

However, in C++14, the expression `S{42}.x` became an xvalue, so if lifetime extension applies here, then it is not because the reference binds to a prvalue.

One might instead claim that lifetime extension only applies once, and binding any other references to the same object do not further extend its lifetime. This would explain why the OP's code creates a dangling reference, without preventing lifetime extension in the `S{42}.x` case. However, there is no statement to this effect in the standard, either.

StoryTeller has also said here that the reference must bind directly, but I don't know what he means by that, either. He cites standards text indicating that binding a reference to a temporary in a `return` statement doesn't extend its lifetime. However, that statement seems to be intended to apply to the case where the temporary in question is created by the full-expression in the `return` statement, since it says the temporary will be destroyed at the end of that full-expression. Clearly that's not the case for the `y+1` temporary, which will instead be destroyed at the end of the full-expression containing the call to `min`. Thus, I tend to think that this statement was not intended to apply to cases like that in the question. Instead, its effect, together with the other limitations on lifetime extension, is to *prevent any temporary object's lifetime from being extended beyond the block scope in which it was created*. But this would not prevent the `y+1` temporary in the question from surviving until the end of `main`.

Thus the question remains: what is the principle that explains why the binding of `ref2` to the temporary in the question doesn't extend that temporary's lifetime?

The wording from the current working draft that I cited earlier was introduced by the resolution of [CWG 1299](https://wg21.link/cwg1299), which was opened in 2011 but only resolved recently (not in time for C++17). In a sense, it clarifies the intuition that the reference must bind "directly", by delineating those cases where the binding is "direct" enough for lifetime extension to occur; it is not, however, so restrictive as to only allow it when the reference binds to a prvalue. It permits lifetime extension in the `S{42}.x` case.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer should be updated since non-`constexpr` version in fact compiles]

**Non-`constexpr` version**

*Demo:* https://godbolt.org/z/_p3njK

*Explanation:* The lifetime of the *rvalue* in question produced by `y + 1` is in fact extended. This is because the `return` type of `min` is reference-to-const i.e `const T&` and whenever you have a reference-to-const *binding directly* to a *rvalue* type, the lifetime of the underlying `rvalue` value is extended till *reference-to-const* exists.

Going further, the reference-to-const output of `min` is then assigned directly to the lvalue name `ref2` whose type is `const int&`; an `int` type should work here too (i.e `int ref2 = min(x, y+1);`) in which case the underlying *rvalue* will be copied over and reference-to-const will be destroyed.

In summary, the non-`constexpr` version should always produce the desired output at least in the latest version of compilers conforming with the modern C++'s standard.

**`constexpr` version**

The issue here is different since the type specifier of `ref2` requires it to be a `constexpr` which in turn requires the expression to be a compile-time literal. Although in theory the lifetime extension could be applied here for `constexpr` reference-to-const types, C++ doesn't permit it yet (i.e it doesn't create temporary `constexpr` types to hold the underlying *rvalues*), perhaps because it prohibits some optimizations or makes the compiler's job harder -- not sure which one is it.

However, you should be able to workaround this case trivially by:

```
constexpr int value = min(x, y + 1);
constexpr int const& ref2 = value;
```