# Why would a std::move of std::shared_ptr casue destruction

Tags: c++, reference, move, shared-ptr

I got some code look like this

```cpp
struct A
{
    int i;
    A(int i) : i(i) {}
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "destroy " << i << endl;
    }
};
using p = shared_ptr<A>;
p f(int i)
{
    return make_shared<A>(i);
}
int main()
{
    auto i = f(1);
    cout << "a" << endl;
    p && j = f(2);
    cout << "a" << endl;
    p && k = move(f(3));
    cout << "a" << endl;
    auto l = move(f(4));
    cout << "a" << endl;
    p ptr = make_shared<A>(5);
    auto && a = move(ptr);
    cout << "a" << endl;
}
```

and the output is

```
a
a
destroy 3
a
a
a
destroy 5
destroy 4
destroy 2
destroy 1
```

I don't understand why `move` a function's return value to a rvalue reference cause destruction. But put it directly to a rvalue reference is ok.

The problem is actually found with `std::get<>` of a `std::tuple`. I have a function that return a tuple of two shared_ptr and use std::get<> to access the element. But I found that `auto && i = get<0>(f())` will cause error but `auto i = get<0>(f())` won't. Then I find a similar but simpler situation for std::move

Comment: Please do not ask XY questions. If you want to query about some `std::get<>` usage with a `std::tuple`, create a separate question for that.

Comment: @KamilCuk: it is a legitimate question about something that can be baffling sometimes.

Comment: My compiler emits warnings on misusing `move` for the `move(f(3))` and `move(f(4))` cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p && j = f(2);
```

Here, `f` returns a prvalue of type `std::shared_ptr<A>`.  When you bind a reference to a prvalue it extends the lifetime of the prvalue to be that of the reference.  That means that the object returned by `f` will have the same lifetime as `j`.

```
p && k = move(f(3));
```

Here, once again `f` returns a prvalue.  `std::move`'s parameter binds to that prvalue, extending its lifetime to the lifetime *of the parameter*.  `std::move` does not return a prvalue though.  It returns an xvalue.  Lifetime extension does not apply to xvalues, so the object returned by `f` gets destroyed as soon as `std::move`'s parameter's lifetime ends.  That is, it gets destroyed when `std::move` returns.  `k` then becomes a dangling reference.

Comment: Lifetime extension does apply to some xvalues, though it is true that it does not apply in this case. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576254/481267

Answer (score 2):

Let’s go through these one by one:

```
auto i = f(1); // (1)
```

This creates a local variable `i` (not a reference) initialized with the return value of `f(1)`. This is OK. The lifetime of `i` is until the end of the block.

```
p && j = f(2); // (2)
```

This initializes the reference `j` with a reference to the object returned by `f(2)`, and this extends the lifetime of the value returned by `f(2)`, so this is OK. The lifetime of `j` is until the end of the block.

```
p && k = move(f(3)); // (3)
```

This initializes the reference with a reference to the object returned by `move`, no lifetime extension occurs since the value returned by `move` is a reference to the temporary returned by `f(2)` (and not a temporary object), but **the temporary returned by `f(2)` dies as soon as `k` is initialized, since its lifetime is not extended (it’s not assigned to a reference variable), and `k` ends up being a dangling reference.**

```
auto l = move(f(4)); // (4)
```

Same as (1), the move is useless. The lifetime of `l` is until the end of the block.

```
p ptr = make_shared<A>(5); // (5)
```

This is a local variable initialization. The lifetime of `ptr` is until the end of the block.

```
auto && a = move(ptr);
```

`a` is a reference to `ptr`. This does not change the lifetime of `ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Because by using `std::move` you've turned the return value into a reference. And not a const reference, so it's a temporary.

So no copy takes place and as soon as the line ends, the return value is destroyed.