# optimising column-wise maximum with SIMD

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics, avx

I have this function where I spent significant amount of time in my code, and I would like to optimise it by vectorization-SIMD-compiler intrinsics, if possible.

It essentially finds the value and the location of the maximum over a matrix over columns, and stores them:

- val_ptr: input matrix: column-major (Fortran-style) n_rows-by-n_cols (where typically n_rows>>n_cols)
- opt_pos_ptr : int vector of length n_rows where to store the position of the maximum. On entry filled with zeros.
- max_ptr: float vector of length n_rows where to store the maximum. On entry filled with copies of the first column of val_ptr
- The function will be called in a parallel loop
- The memory region are guaranteed to be not overlapping
- I don't really need the max_ptr to be filled, currently it is just used for book-keeping and to avoid memory allocation
- I use MSVC, C++17 on Windows 10. Meant to run modern Intel CPUs

The code, where the template type are meant to be float or double:

```
template <typename eT>
find_max(const int n_cols, 
         const int n_rows, 
         const eT* val_ptr,
         int* opt_pos_ptr,
         eT* max_ptr){
    for (int col = 1; col < n_cols; ++col)
    {
        //Getting the pointer to the beginning of the column
        const auto* value_col = val_ptr + col * n_rows;
        //Looping over the rows
        for (int row = 0; row < n_rows; ++row)
        {
            //If the value is larger than the current maximum, we replace and we store its positions
            if (value_col[row] > max_ptr[row])
            {
                max_ptr[row] = value_col[row];
                opt_pos_ptr[row] = col;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried so far:

- I tried to use OpenMP parallel for on the inner loop, but brings something only on very large rows, bit larger than my current usage.
- The if in inner loop prevents #pragma omp simd to work, and I was not able to rewrite it without it.

Comment: The meaning of “rows” and “columns” appears swapped here. In C, we usually refer to the set of `A[i][j]` for a fixed `i` as rows and the set of `A[i][j]` for a fixed `j` as columns, and C address is such that `&A[i][j] = `&A[0][0] + i*NumberOfColumns + j`, but `val_ptr + col * n_rows` is swapped from that convention.

Comment: I edited the question, to fix the error and add more details. You are right: I use column-major layout as I use Armadillo to manage my matrices, and I usually go down to pointers to do the heavy lifting, as in this case

Comment: I think the templated type will make use of intrinsics difficult. If eT was say double you could get rid of the if using fmax to get the max and ?: for the opt_pos_ptr. If you must use the templated type it would be polite to remove the C tag from your question

Comment: Tag removed. Can you please point me to the docs of the feature you mentioned? Template is not really necessary, I could write 2 separate implementation for float and double, which are my main usages

Comment: For fmax seaching for 'fmax c++' yields hits, eg https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmax  You can replace if ( cond) { opt[row] = col; } with opt[row] = cond ? col : opt[row]; Both fmax and ?: look as if they could involve branches, but the compiler could use conditional stores instead. Of course whether this is any improvement only measurement will tell.

Comment: Maybe `omp for` on the outter loop work? And using local variable to prevent several processors continually accessing adjacent memory.

Comment: has the matrix any more structure? For a montone matrix for example you can do this in n*log n. (monotone matrix: The indices of the maximum element of each column are either always increasing to decreasing)

Comment: No, for all purpose one can assume that the values are random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code sample you posted, it looks like you want to compute a vertical maximum value, meaning that in your case "columns" are horizontal. In C/C++ horizontal sequences of elements (i.e. where two adjacent elements have distance of one element in memory) are normally called rows and vertical (where two adjacent elements have distance of row size in memory) - columns. In my answer below I will be using the traditional terminology, where rows are horizontal and columns are vertical.

Also, for brevity I will be focusing on one possible type of the matrix element - `float`. The basic idea is the same for `double`, with the main difference being the number of elements per vector and the `_ps`/`_pd` intrinsics selection. I'll provide a version for `double` at the end.

---

The idea is that you can compute vertical maximum for multiple columns in parallel using `_mm_max_ps`/`_mm_max_pd`. In order to also record the position of the found maximum, you can compare the previous maximum with the current elements. The result of the comparison is a mask, where the elements are all-ones where the maximum is updated. That mask can be used to select which position needs to be updated as well.

I must note that the algorithm below assumes that it is not important which max element's position is recorded, if there are multiple equal max elements in a column. Also, I assume the matrix does not contain NaN values, which would affect the comparisons. More on this later.

```
void find_max(const int n_cols, 
         const int n_rows, 
         const float* val_ptr,
         int* opt_pos_ptr,
         float* max_ptr){
    const __m128i mm_one = _mm_set1_epi32(1);

    // Pre-compute the number of rows that can be processed in full vector width.
    // In a 128-bit vector there are 4 floats or 2 doubles
    int tail_size = n_rows & 3;
    int n_rows_aligned = n_rows - tail_size;
    int row = 0;
    for (; row < n_rows_aligned; row += 4)
    {
        const auto* col_ptr = val_ptr + row;
        __m128 mm_max = _mm_loadu_ps(col_ptr);
        __m128i mm_max_pos = _mm_setzero_si128();
        __m128i mm_pos = mm_one;
        col_ptr += n_rows;
        for (int col = 1; col < n_cols; ++col)
        {
            __m128 mm_value = _mm_loadu_ps(col_ptr);

            // See if this value is greater than the old maximum
            __m128 mm_mask = _mm_cmplt_ps(mm_max, mm_value);
            // If it is, save its position
            mm_max_pos = _mm_blendv_epi8(mm_max_pos, mm_pos, _mm_castps_si128(mm_mask));

            // Compute the maximum
            mm_max = _mm_max_ps(mm_value, mm_max);

            mm_pos = _mm_add_epi32(mm_pos, mm_one);
            col_ptr += n_rows;
        }

        // Store the results
        _mm_storeu_ps(max_ptr + row, mm_max);
        _mm_storeu_si128(reinterpret_cast< __m128i* >(opt_pos_ptr + row), mm_max_pos);
    }

    // Process tail serially
    for (; row < n_rows; ++row)
    {
        const auto* col_ptr = val_ptr + row;
        auto max = *col_ptr;
        int max_pos = 0;
        col_ptr += n_rows;
        for (int col = 1; col < n_cols; ++col)
        {
            auto value = *col_ptr;
            if (value > max)
            {
                max = value;
                max_pos = col;
            }

            col_ptr += n_rows;
        }

        max_ptr[row] = max;
        opt_pos_ptr[row] = max_pos;
    }
}
```

The code above requires SSE4.1 because of the blending intrinsics. You can replace those with a combination of `_mm_and_si128`/`_ps`, `_mm_andnot_si128`/`_ps` and `_mm_or_si128`/`_ps`, in which case the requirements will be lowered to SSE2. See [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) for more details on the particular intrinsics, including which instruction set extensions they require.

---

A note about NaN values. If your matrix can have NaNs, the `_mm_cmplt_ps` test will always return false. As for `_mm_max_ps`, it is generally not known what it will return. The `maxps` instruction that the intrinsic translates to returns its second (source) operand if either of the operands is a NaN, so by arranging the operands of the instruction you can achieve either behavior. However, it is not documented which argument of the `_mm_max_ps` intrinsic represents which operand of the instruction, and it is even possible that the compiler may use different association in different cases. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199125/4636534) answer for more details.

In order to ensure the correct behavior wrt. NaNs you could use inline assembler to force the correct order of `maxps` operands. Unfortunately, that is not an option with MSVC for x86-64 target, which you said you're using, so instead you could reuse the `_mm_cmplt_ps` result for a second blend like this:

```
// Compute the maximum
mm_max = _mm_blendv_ps(mm_max, mm_value, mm_mask);
```

This will suppress NaNs in the resulting max values. If you want to keep NaNs instead, you could use a second comparison to detect NaNs:

```
// Detect NaNs
__m128 mm_nan_mask = _mm_cmpunord_ps(mm_value, mm_value);

// Compute the maximum
mm_max = _mm_blendv_ps(mm_max, mm_value, _mm_or_ps(mm_mask, mm_nan_mask));
```

---

You could probably further improve performance of the algorithm above if you use wider vectors (`__m256` or `__m512`) and unroll the outer loop by a small factor, so that at least a cache line worth of row data is loaded on every iteration of the inner loop.

---

Here is an example of implementation for `double`. The important point to note here is that because there are only two `double` elements per vector and there are still four positions per vector, we have to unroll the outer loop to process two vectors of `double` at a time and then compress the two masks from comparisons with the previous maximums to blend the 32-bit positions.

```
void find_max(const int n_cols, 
         const int n_rows, 
         const double* val_ptr,
         int* opt_pos_ptr,
         double* max_ptr){
    const __m128i mm_one = _mm_set1_epi32(1);

    // Pre-compute the number of rows that can be processed in full vector width.
    // In a 128-bit vector there are 2 doubles, but we want to process
    // two vectors at a time.
    int tail_size = n_rows & 3;
    int n_rows_aligned = n_rows - tail_size;
    int row = 0;
    for (; row < n_rows_aligned; row += 4)
    {
        const auto* col_ptr = val_ptr + row;
        __m128d mm_max1 = _mm_loadu_pd(col_ptr);
        __m128d mm_max2 = _mm_loadu_pd(col_ptr + 2);
        __m128i mm_max_pos = _mm_setzero_si128();
        __m128i mm_pos = mm_one;
        col_ptr += n_rows;
        for (int col = 1; col < n_cols; ++col)
        {
            __m128d mm_value1 = _mm_loadu_pd(col_ptr);
            __m128d mm_value2 = _mm_loadu_pd(col_ptr + 2);

            // See if this value is greater than the old maximum
            __m128d mm_mask1 = _mm_cmplt_pd(mm_max1, mm_value1);
            __m128d mm_mask2 = _mm_cmplt_pd(mm_max2, mm_value2);
            // Compress the 2 masks into one
            __m128i mm_mask = _mm_packs_epi32(
                _mm_castpd_si128(mm_mask1), _mm_castpd_si128(mm_mask2));
            // If it is, save its position
            mm_max_pos = _mm_blendv_epi8(mm_max_pos, mm_pos, mm_mask);

            // Compute the maximum
            mm_max1 = _mm_max_pd(mm_value1, mm_max1);
            mm_max2 = _mm_max_pd(mm_value2, mm_max2);

            mm_pos = _mm_add_epi32(mm_pos, mm_one);
            col_ptr += n_rows;
        }

        // Store the results
        _mm_storeu_pd(max_ptr + row, mm_max1);
        _mm_storeu_pd(max_ptr + row + 2, mm_max2);
        _mm_storeu_si128(reinterpret_cast< __m128i* >(opt_pos_ptr + row), mm_max_pos);
    }

    // Process 2 doubles at once
    if (tail_size >= 2)
    {
        const auto* col_ptr = val_ptr + row;
        __m128d mm_max1 = _mm_loadu_pd(col_ptr);
        __m128i mm_max_pos = _mm_setzero_si128();
        __m128i mm_pos = mm_one;
        col_ptr += n_rows;
        for (int col = 1; col < n_cols; ++col)
        {
            __m128d mm_value1 = _mm_loadu_pd(col_ptr);

            // See if this value is greater than the old maximum
            __m128d mm_mask1 = _mm_cmplt_pd(mm_max1, mm_value1);
            // Compress the mask. The upper half doesn't matter.
            __m128i mm_mask = _mm_packs_epi32(
                _mm_castpd_si128(mm_mask1), _mm_castpd_si128(mm_mask1));
            // If it is, save its position
            mm_max_pos = _mm_blendv_epi8(mm_max_pos, mm_pos, mm_mask);

            // Compute the maximum
            mm_max1 = _mm_max_pd(mm_value1, mm_max1);

            mm_pos = _mm_add_epi32(mm_pos, mm_one);
            col_ptr += n_rows;
        }

        // Store the results
        _mm_storeu_pd(max_ptr + row, mm_max1);
        // Only store the lower two positions
        _mm_storel_epi64(reinterpret_cast< __m128i* >(opt_pos_ptr + row), mm_max_pos);

        row += 2;
    }

    // Process tail serially
    for (; row < n_rows; ++row)
    {
        const auto* col_ptr = val_ptr + row;
        auto max = *col_ptr;
        int max_pos = 0;
        col_ptr += n_rows;
        for (int col = 1; col < n_cols; ++col)
        {
            auto value = *col_ptr;
            if (value > max)
            {
                max = value;
                max_pos = col;
            }

            col_ptr += n_rows;
        }

        max_ptr[row] = max;
        opt_pos_ptr[row] = max_pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: `_mm_cmplt_ps` in parallel with `_mm_max_ps` instead of `eq` after would have more ILP, and maybe help with NaN issues if you use it carefully.  Also, doing at least 1 full cache line of vectors while striding along would be a good idea, especially if data is aligned by 64 or 128, so you touch each cache line all at once, not separated across passes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, yes, `_mm_cmplt_ps` is indeed better. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I think `_mm_max_ps` is *supposed* to respect the argument order, like asm.  But GCC before GCC7 treated it as commutative even without `-ffast-math`, so in practice you can only use this safely on clang, ICC, and maybe MSVC (I didn't test MSVC).
see  [What is the instruction that gives branchless FP min and max on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40196817).  But yes, if you want portability to GCC6 and earlier, you need to assume compilers will treat it as commutative and not rely in its NaN behaviour.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did not find any indication of argument to operand association in SDM or Intel Intrinsics Guide, so unless you want to rely on (undocumented) behavior of a particular compiler, it's better to write portable code. It's ironic how asm block can be more portable in this case.

Comment: The intrinsics guide's pseudo-code does include `dst[i+31:i] := MAX(a[i+31:i], b[i+31:i])`.  This somewhat weakly implies that it's performing the same MAX operation as the asm instruction, using the intrinsic args in that order.
https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=maxps&expand=3649.  It would be reasonable to base an argument on that scrap of documentation.  (Especially by reference to the MAX function definition in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/maxps#operation). GCC <= 6 spoils it for practical purposes, but that is a bug IMO, not implementation choice

Comment: Great job! There are no special rule on entries with the same values, and no nans are expected. Your code is indeed way faster, and I will accept it.
I would have few question, or curiosities if you like, as I am new to this:
-  int tail_size = n_rows & 3; Why this, rather than n_rows % 4? Just faster?
- the width of the vector depends on the kind of CPU used, right? With the 512 supported only of few Intel CPU. 
- your code which instruction set does employ?

Comment: @EnzoFerrazzano > n_rows & 3; Why this, rather than n_rows % 4? -- Mostly just my preference to ensure good performance no matter what. A decent optimizing compiler would generate the same code for modulus by a constant when optimization is on. When not on, it might generate a true division, but in that case you don't care about performance. In some cases it may be useful to still have reasonably fast code even in debug builds, when optimization is not enabled, so when possible I prefer to write code that is less reliant on compiler optimizations.

Comment: @EnzoFerrazzano > the width of the vector depends on the kind of CPU used, right? -- The *available* width of the vector, yes. But in order to make use of wider vectors, you have to write versions of this algorithm using wider vectors, and use a runtime dispatch based on supported CPU features to dynamically select the version of the algorithm in runtime.

Comment: @EnzoFerrazzano > your code which instruction set does employ? -- The code in my answer uses SSE4.1 because of the blending intrinsics. You can replace those with a combination of `_mm_and_si128`/`_ps`, `_mm_andnot_si128`/`_ps` and `_mm_or_si128`/`_ps`, in which case the requirements will be lowered to SSE2. A 256-bit vector version will likely require AVX2 and 512-bit - AVX-512.

Comment: @EnzoFerrazzano You can use Intel Intrinsics Guide (https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) to find out more about individual intrinsics, including which instruction set extensions they require.

Comment: @AndreySemashev Thanks for all the suggestions. A lot to read up! I am trying to make it work for doubles and longer vectors.
For doubles I have some funny behaviour: trivially replacing the functions with *_pd  and the variables __m128d, the maximum found are correct, but the position of the odd rows are wrong (actually copies of the previous). 
When copying the result back into opt_pos_ptr I get someting like [... p p q q ...] instead of [... p q ... ... ], where p and q are the correct positions. 
There must be an unexpected behaviour in the second line of the inner loop.

Comment: @EnzoFerrazzano The positions are duplicated because `mm_pos` and `mm_max_pos` have 4 32-bit indexes and the result of `_mm_cmplt_pd` is a mask of 2 64-bit all-ones or all-zeros. You can unroll the outer loop to process 4 `double`s (2 `__m128d` vectors) at once and then compress the masks from `_mm_cmplt_pd`s using `_mm_packs_epi32`.

Comment: you mean by processing two rows together (separated, i.e. row and row +2), each row will produce a mm_max_pos, then join them with _mm_packs_epi32? It does not seems to work, but most likely I am just out of my depth here –

Comment: @EnzoFerrazzano > you mean by processing two rows together (separated, i.e. row and row +2) -- Yes. >  each row will produce a mm_max_pos, then join them with _mm_packs_epi32 -- No, I mean produce two masks, then join the two masks to one using `_mm_packs_epi32` and use that combined mask to blend `mm_max_pos` and `mm_pos`, as in my answer.

Comment: @EnzoFerrazzano I've updated the answer with a version for `double`.