# _mm_max_ss has different behavior between clang and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, clang, sse

I'm trying to cross compile a project using clang and gcc but I'm seeing some odd differences when using `_mm_max_ss` e.g.

```
__m128 a = _mm_set_ss(std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN());
__m128 b = _mm_set_ss(2.0f);
__m128 c = _mm_max_ss(a,b);
__m128 d = _mm_max_ss(b,a);
```

Now I expected `std::max` type behavior when NaNs are involved but clang and gcc give different results:

```
Clang: (what I expected)
c: 2.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
d: nan 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 

Gcc: (Seems to ignore order)
c: nan 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
d: nan 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

_mm_max_ps does the expected thing when I use it. I've tried using `-ffast-math`, `-fno-fast-math` but it doesn't seem to have an effect.  Any ideas to make the behavior similar across compilers?

Godbolt link [here](https://godbolt.org/z/7jTbPP)

Comment: This well-written post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199125/12939557 talks about your issue and it explains why this is happening. However, it seems that this issue should have been fixed in GCC 7 while it is obviously still there in the latest version of GCC... I think it is wise to open a ticket for this on the GCC bug tracker.

Comment: i have filed a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99497 for the main issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that IEEE-754 requires: `(NaN cmp x)` to return `false` for *all* `cmp` operators `{==, <, <=, >, >=}`, except `{!=}` which returns `true`.  An implementation of a **`max()`** function might be defined in terms of any of the inequality operators.

So, the question is, how is `_mm_max_ps` implemented? With `{<, <=, >, >=}`, or a bit comparison?

Interestingly, when *disabling* optimization in your link, the corresponding **`maxss`** instruction is used by both gcc and clang. Both yield:

```
2.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
nan 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

This suggests, given: `max(NaN, 2.0f) -> 2.0f`, that: `max(a, b) = (a op b) ? a : b`, where `op` is one of: `{<, <=, >, >=}`. With IEEE-754 rules, the result of this comparison is always false, so:

`(NaN op val)` is *always* false, returning `(val)`,
`(val op NaN)` is *always* false, returning `(NaN)`

With optimization on, the compiler is free to precompute `(c)` and `(d)` at compile time. It appears that clang evaluates the results as the **`maxss`** instruction would - correct 'as-if' behaviour. GCC is either falling back on another implementation of **`max()`** - it uses the GMP and MPFR libraries  for compile-time numerics - or is just being careless with the `_mm_max_ss` semantics.

GCC is still getting it wrong with 10.2 and trunk versions on godbolt. So I think you've found a bug! I haven't answered the second part, because I can't think of an all-purpose hack that will efficiently work around this.

---

From Intel's ISA reference:

> If the values being compared are both 0.0s (of either sign), the value
> in the second source operand is returned. If a value in the second
> source operand is an SNaN, that SNaN is returned unchanged to the
> destination (that is, a QNaN version of the SNaN is not returned).
>
> If only one value is a NaN (SNaN or QNaN) for this instruction, the
> second source operand, either a NaN or a valid floating-point value,
> is written to the result. If instead of this behavior, it is required
> that the NaN from either source operand be returned, the action of
> MAXSS can be emulated using a sequence of instructions, such as, a
> comparison followed by AND, ANDN and OR.

Comment: If I'd seen the answer linked in the comment above, I probably wouldn't have bothered! In any case it must still be regarded as a bug in gcc. It may also be significant that there are two different NaN encodings in the gcc asm: `0x7fc00000` and `0x7ff80000` - Something strange going on there...

Comment: I appreciate that you did, as it gives some extra context to the situation.