# Horizontal min on avx2 8 float register and shuffle paired registers alongside

Tags: c++, simd, sse, avx, avx2

After ray vs triangle intersection test in 8 wide simd, I'm left with updating t, u and v which I've done in scalar below (find lowest t and updating t,u,v if lower than previous t). Is there a way to do this in simd instead of scalar?

```
int update_tuv(__m256 t, __m256 u, __m256 v, float* t_out, float* u_out, float* v_out)
{
    alignas(32) float ts[8];_mm256_store_ps(ts, t);
    alignas(32) float us[8];_mm256_store_ps(us, u);
    alignas(32) float vs[8];_mm256_store_ps(vs, v);
    
    int min_index{0};    
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; ++i) {
        if (ts[i] < ts[min_index]) {
            min_index = i;
        }
    }

    if (ts[min_index] >= *t_out) { return -1; }

    *t_out = ts[min_index];
    *u_out = us[min_index];
    *v_out = vs[min_index];

    return min_index;
}
```

I haven't found a solution that finds the horizontal min t and shuffles/permutes it's pairing u and v along the way other than permuting and min testing 8 times.

Comment: Do you need to update `{t,u,v}_out` after each call to `update_tuv` or do you call that method a lot and are just interested in the end-result? Generally, you should try to avoid horizontal reductions when doing SIMD (at least for SSE/AVX), so if possible do a lot of parallel reductions and just one final horizontal reduction at the end.

Comment: u,v only the end result, but t_out is required for the next iteration. @chtz

Comment: I don't think storing `t_out` is necessary, if you have a `__m256 t_min` instead (unless of course it is required to calculate the next `t, u, v`). Can you show your main loop? (Maybe ask it as a follow-up question, so the current answer is not invalidated)

Comment: @chtz the (simplified) mainloop is just Möller–Trumbore intersect algorithm 8 wide many times which doesn't have to depend on previous `t_out`. You're saying you can keep `{t, u, v}_out` as 256 bit registers for the lowest `t` right and extract at the end of the loop? Then you still have similar problem of keeping the 256bit registers that contains the lowest `t`.

Comment: Yes, you will still need something equivalent to this at the end, but you especially don't need the branch and the shuffles inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find horizontal minimum of the `t` vector. This alone is enough to reject values with your first test.
Then find index of that first minimum element, extract and store that lane from `u` and `v` vectors.

```
// Horizontal minimum of the vector
inline float horizontalMinimum( __m256 v )
{
    __m128 i = _mm256_extractf128_ps( v, 1 );
    i = _mm_min_ps( i, _mm256_castps256_ps128( v ) );
    i = _mm_min_ps( i, _mm_movehl_ps( i, i ) );
    i = _mm_min_ss( i, _mm_movehdup_ps( i ) );
    return _mm_cvtss_f32( i );
}

int update_tuv_avx2( __m256 t, __m256 u, __m256 v, float* t_out, float* u_out, float* v_out )
{
    // Find the minimum t, reject if t_out is larger than that
    float current = *t_out;
    float ts = horizontalMinimum( t );
    if( ts >= current )
        return -1;
    // Should compile into vbroadcastss
    __m256 tMin = _mm256_set1_ps( ts );
    *t_out = ts;

    // Find the minimum index
    uint32_t mask = (uint32_t)_mm256_movemask_ps( _mm256_cmp_ps( t, tMin, _CMP_EQ_OQ ) );
    // If you don't yet have C++/20, use _tzcnt_u32 or _BitScanForward or __builtin_ctz intrinsics
    int minIndex = std::countr_zero( mask );

    // Prepare a permutation vector for the vpermps AVX2 instruction
    // We don't care what's in the highest 7 integer lanes in that vector, only need the first lane
    __m256i iv = _mm256_castsi128_si256( _mm_cvtsi32_si128( (int)minIndex ) );

    // Permute u and v vector, moving that element to the first lane
    u = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps( u, iv );
    v = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps( v, iv );

    // Update the outputs with the new numbers
    *u_out = _mm256_cvtss_f32( u );
    *v_out = _mm256_cvtss_f32( v );
    return minIndex;
}
```

While relatively straightforward and probably faster than your current method with vector stores followed by scalar loads, the performance of the above function is only great when that `if` branch is well-predicted.

When that branch is unpredictable (statistically, results in random outcomes), a completely branchless implementation might be a better fit. Gonna be more complicated though, load old values with `_mm_load_ss`, conditionally update with `_mm_blendv_ps`, and store back with `_mm_store_ss`.

Comment: Since you want a broadcast hmin, you could use `vperm2f128` instead of `vextractf128`, and 256-bit in-lane shuffles after that.  Same number of shuffles and `vminps`, but they'd be on YMM vectors. Same speed except on Zen1, but saves a `vbroadcastss`.

Comment: How does this handle NaNs, or -Inf being the minimum?  `-INFINITY == -INFINITY` is true, so it'll work in that case.  But remember that `_mm_min_ps` [is not commutative for NaN inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196817/what-is-the-instruction-that-gives-branchless-fp-min-and-max-on-x86), except for buggy GCC versions where it might reverse the operands.  (We don't care about signed zero here; `cmpps` treats +-0.0 as equal to each other.)

Comment: It performs about the same, will do better testing after replacing the if with a blend later